# Width is not present on inspect element but showing on page

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi guys can anyone help me with this problem? I'm having a hard time looking for this width. When I'm checking it on the computed tab there's a width of 2290px but when I check the CSS it's width: inherit. Can anyone help me how to make this 100%. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I tried adding !important on my css still not working

Comment: Problem solved :) By adding display property the width gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :) By adding display property the width gone :)